# How can I hang ceramic art on drywall?

Tags: drywall

Artist recommends using 4" dry wall screws inserted at an angle to hang his art.  This does not look sturdy.  Any ideas ?  The art is a large ceramic tic tac where 2" of the screw is inserted in one end for hanging purposes.

Comment: For starters, how much does it weigh? When you say drywall screws, do you mean regular drywall screws, or drywall anchors? Can you shift the artwork sideways a little bit so you can hit a stud?

Comment: I am not sure an artist is the best place to get advice on how to hang stuff on a wall.  Most large art does not have a "hole" to hang things because this cause projections and tilting.

Comment: Running this screw into a stud is the only way it will hold up at the angle needed to hold the artwork in place

Comment: Drywall itself is only 3/8 or 1/2 inch thick in most applications. Even with 2" sticking out, a 4" screw just sticks  1 1/2" into a hollow cavity.

Answer (score 1):

You are much better off using an anchor that is probably way over engineered for your artwork.  For instance I would get a 150 lb anchor (or even better) like [this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_114767-10337-50300_0__?productId=3183811&Ntt=250%20drywall%20anchor&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=250%2bdrywall%2banchor&facetInfo=).  If you go straight into the stud you can really need a thicker screw for a lot of weight or it could sag.  Problem I would foresee is the hole in artwork for screw not being big or deep enough for said screw.

Comment: I need to hang 14 of these pieces in a 7 x7 area, each weighs about 1 lb.

Comment: There are smaller self screw anchors but the example would work for that too - or its little brother.

Answer (score 0):

OP commented that each piece is only 1 lb.   At this tiny weight, anything will do the job.   If you can guarantee no one will touch them, any kind of nail or screw is perfectly fine.   If you need something a little sturdier, use any kind of drywall anchor you can find.   This will prevent movement and damage to the drywall if any of the pieces are bumped.